# Encoding byte data to base64 crashes for some byte data in vb6

Tags: string, vb6, base64, byte

I have the following code to convert byte data to base64 string :

```
ReDim g_Template(dwLen) As Byte

    i = 0
    Do While Len(m_strTemplate) > 0
        iPos = InStr(1, m_strTemplate, "$")
        If (iPos > 0) Then
            g_Template(i) = Mid(m_strTemplate, 1, iPos - 1)
            m_strTemplate = Right(m_strTemplate, Len(m_strTemplate) - iPos)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Dim DM, EL
         Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
         ' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
         Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
         EL.dataType = "bin.base64"
         ' Set bytes, get encoded String
         EL.nodeTypedValue = g_Template
         FingerData = EL.Text
```

But this code crashes for the following byte data :

```
  A123            
 +#wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww; ;:61wwwwwwwwwww :8531.wwwwwwwww  :6430/0wwwwwwww ;:63200.-wwwwww :9631/.--wwwwww:8620.,,-wwwww   8750-,++,wwwww  

82-+++*)wwww 9/+**)**wwwww8.*)((((wwww9.)))&%$!www! !,,+++'')wwwww$%$#&)+,++)((wwww)(('&(+./.,+(wwwww,+****/000/.-wwwwww,--//243441/wwwwww0///0477777:wwwwww232w3589888wwwwwwwww6579::74wwwwwwwwww;959  8wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwHgQ;6+0L:?/3?MHAh4 @DK1X&"s&^N[RM`                                   U€„@DFGMSW[^_eggglllowxx{{}…‡Œ–š                                   




                                    ,wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww,3ww3wwwwwwwwwwww&'-53wwwwwwwwwww%81wwwwwwwww;62 8/,wwwwwww64(+07474,)'wwwwww6*%"!'12/+('wwwww#  "!!%*,+*((wwwww""#$%'***)))wwwwww&&'((()*+,++wwwwww,))*)(),/00/wwwwww/-..-+,13332wwwwww//211/057766wwwwww1343443799;wwwwww45644669;: wwwwwww665679;;97:wwwwwww75599:;902wwwwwwwww;8;;;;94wwwwwwwwww :  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwKhShS{kH\Aad_[_XIWmTBfbLN9J0N[*AvL'o;/v6ZNH\                          '4;<A]_px†‡$,/0124688>CCCE]]_befggkuyy{{ƒˆˆ                          






                            &)wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww*,*wwwwwwwww#'..w)0wwwwww" w5w12wwwwww!"w/:

wwwwww  %*.9    $wwwww# !',18#wwwww $'.49wwwww!%(*/48
wwww$&(*-048 
wwww)*+-0248;wwwwww.-/3567:wwwwww../358;;  :wwwwww43246: ;; ;:wwwwww76789:;;;;::wwwwww9:;;::; ;::wwwwwww;:; ;;;;;:9wwwwwwww:;9: ;8: wwwwwwwww  ;;;:89wwwwwwwwwww   9:;wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww:wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwS3>jg0Yoao23XT\5UY:ZHQ(wRlNA:/E--@;.JCKML                             89C\chiippx‰‘*-ABRT]abdjrx|‚‹Ž•–™œž                             




                                 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww   :87wwwwwwwww
;8633wwwwwww
;8631wwwwwww    ;8620wwwwwww
;8532wwwwwww
;73111wwwwww
50011wwwwww 60//.wwwwww:.,-,wwwwww#**++wwwwww !"!%)*,.wwwwwww  "$%%*,*,/wwwwwww%%$%(,-++.0wwwwwwww'''-20--06wwwwwwwww,*/21/.w:wwwwwwwww-w033wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwZfV:>NC9NZV]t3fb=bUG\                                                 hrs&+,07?BCIVXY_eegŠŠ                                                 



                                                  2wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww3wwwwwwwwwwww989642013wwwwwwww;;86663011wwwwwwww; ;667300.wwwwwwww; ;8764210/wwwwww :863232222wwwww:8643333212www 
;9975431011wwww
 ::97542001wwww;9865431011www :7664430//www  :7764320./www:7763310/0www :64211002www 73100111wwww;7310/000www89;851/0100wwwwww:521123wwwwwww
 743124wwwwwww

953+wwwwwwwww   
;850wwwwwwwwww


wwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwAgE40WH=K-EFDc                                                      (:@NPV`oss‡‰“–—™
```

Why does this code crash for this byte data ? How can I modify the code for working well ?

Comment: What is the error message you are given?

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem does not lie with your code but the temp file that you create or try to open. 500 Internal Server Error is a generalized error returned from your server because it cannot pinpoint the actual error.

Try to use a local file/create a local file, if all works then  your call to your server is throwing an exception. Normal checks will be calls made to the file which is not referenced or there to be called upon, server authentication failed etc.